# Creating a list of empty lists in numba

Tags: python, numba

Why does foo function bellow work and bar one does not? What am I missing here?

```
@numba.njit                                           
def foo(x):                                           
    return [[i for i in range(0)] for _ in range(x)]

@numba.njit                                           
def bar(x):                                           
    return [[] for _ in range(x)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar` creates an empty list. numba needs to infer the types of all variables that are used in `nopython` mode to compile your code (and `njit` only compiles to nopython mode). But an empty list cannot be typed, since numba won't be able to infer the type of the items stored in the list (since there are none). Just try the following to get a more "descriptive" error message:

```
numba.typeof([])
```

If you use object mode (for example with the `jit` decorator without specifying `nopython=True`), you can use untyped python objects, at the cost of a slower execution performance.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm wondering how numba infers the type of the empty lists in `foo`. It actually creates a list of empty int lists (which is what I need). Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You are welcome. You may also accept my answer, this will also give you a few points. I'd avoid creating a list of empty int lists, since you can't assign any value to these empty int lists, neither in python, nor in nopython mode. But this is more suitable for a new question as follow up question, since it is not related to you initial question. It is much more likely that you get an answer on that when you ask a new question which is specifically asking this.